# Can't hide constructor at [incr Tcl]

Tags: oop, constructor, tcl, private, incr-tcl

Consider the code below.

```
package require Itcl 

::itcl::class A \ 
{ 
private { 
    constructor { } { } { puts "==== at A::constructor" } 

    method f { } { puts "==== at A::f" } 
} 
} 

A a ;# PASSES

a f ;# fails
```

For class `A` the constructor is private, but it is still possible to define an object of `A`.

Am I doing something wrong, or incr Tcl is designed to behave so?

Comment: I understand the whole brace-on-its-own-line religion, but I've never understood why people insist on using it in languages where it's not supported without extra syntactic cruft. <shrug>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is the way itcl work, if you look at the specification for a class:

```
itcl::class className {
inherit baseClass ?baseClass...? 
constructor args ?init? body 
destructor body 
method name ?args? ?body? 
proc name ?args? ?body? 
variable varName ?init? ?config? 
common varName ?init? 
public command ?arg arg ...? 
protected command ?arg arg ...? 
private command ?arg arg ...? 
set varName ?value? 
array option ?arg arg ...? 
} 
className objName ?arg arg ...? 
objName method ?arg arg ...? 
className::proc ?arg arg ...?
```

you can see that private/protected can be applied to command but not to the constrcutor or the destructor.  Looking [here](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1212) at the documentation on the itcl design patterns may also give some clues as to how to achieve something close to a private constructor.

Comment: I found no way to obtain a private constructor. Seems it is just a language defect.

Comment: @ Vahagn It's just the way that the people who wrote Itcl decided to implement constructors and without knowing why they did it this way I'd be relucatanct to say it was a defect. What do you want to do that you really must have privte constuctors?